# How to append the yesterday date to table name while renaming in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using MySQLi Object-oriented method for mysqli connection in php. In that, I need a query to rename the table to yesterday's date. How can I do it?

Here is my code:

```
 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("RENAME TABLE current_table_tmp TO SUBDATE(CURDATE(),1)");
 $stmt->execute();
```

My error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean
```

Comment: Your Error as nothing to do with the topic: how to rename a table. So what do want to know? SQL would be `RENAME TABLE tbl_name TO new_tbl_name` and better use `date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1day'))` and `date('Y-m-d')`  change `Y-m-d` to your given format.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions i need to rename the table by yesterday date?

Comment: 8-) Then do it! `print date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-1day'));` gives you `2017-04-23`

Comment: you never rename your tables based on the date in the first place

Comment: JustOnUnderMillions i need a query to rename a table by yesterday date

Comment: Your Common Sense okey, so what can i do for append yesterday date to table name in mysql

Comment: you never  append a yesterday date to a table name in mysql. you just keep your table name as is, if you don't get it yet

Comment: use name  tbl_2017_04_03

Comment: okey, i accept that ,if there is any way present to rename or modify the table name by yesterday date?

Comment: Gopi Chand i need mysql query for that!

Comment: i got answer by using multi_query

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you found an answer to your own question, please don't edit your question, but post an answer. The **Question**-section is, as the name hints, reserved for questions only, whilest there is a special section for **Answers** only. Then, after 3 days, come back, and mark your answer as accepted, so everyone knows, there are no worries left.

Comment: Bad form to edit a question to include an answer. An answer to a question should be posted as an **Answer**. As is, this question does *not* have an answer.

Comment: @derM&@spencer7593 i accept that and i changed my question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer by using multi_query to execute dynamic SQL statement

Here is my php code:

```
    $location = 'renametable.sql';
    $commands = file_get_contents($location);   
    $this->conn->multi_query($commands);
```

dynamic SQL statement to append the yesterday date as a renametable.sql file

```
SET @tablename = 'current_table_tmp';

SELECT @query := CONCAT('RENAME TABLE `', @tablename, '` TO `', 
    CURDATE(), @tablename, '`');

PREPARE STMT FROM @query;
EXECUTE STMT;
```